# if all of the world used IPV6, there is no need to have mac address anymore?

Tags: ipv6, mac-address

Mac address can not replace IP address, because Mac address is immutable, and there is no Prefix concept in Mac address. So why IpV6 can not replace Mac address? Do we still need Mac address when all of us are using IP V6?

Comment: Different data-link protocols use different addressing. The IEEE protocols use MAC addressing, and some use 48-bit MAC addresses, and some use 64-bit MAC addresses. Other protocols use other, or even no, addressing. For example PPP has only two possible hosts, so addressing is not needed, frame relay uses DLCI, ATM uses VPI/VCI, etc. IPv6 is a network-layer protocol that can be carried by any data-link protocol, but the data-link protocol still needs its own addressing.

Comment: just look at the OSI Model, mac is a other layer as IP so to say it "easy", first the mac is communicating and afterwards the IP

Answer (score 2):

IEEE 802 networks (like Ethernet and Wifi) would still require MAC addresses to function.